# Error 404 Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts2

Un saludo, estoy tratando de construir un *Hello World* con [esta guía](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_examples.htm) utilizando el Framework de apache struts2.

Pero no me funciona. Cuando ingreso el nombre y hago *submit* me arroja error 404

[image: http error 404]

Este es mi arbol de directorio

[image: arbol de directorio]

mi archivo struts.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
   <constant name = "struts.devMode" value = "true" />
   
   <package name = "helloworld" extends = "struts-default">
     <action name = "hello" 
         class = "com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
         method = "execute">
         <result name = "success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

Y mi web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
 
   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Por último, el formulario que utilizo para enviar los datos:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "s" uri = "/struts-tags"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
      <form action = "hello">
         <label for = "name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
         <input type = "text" name = "name"/>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Say Hello"/>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Haciendo pruebas me di cuenta que en el formulario estaba usando etiquetas HTML normales y debía usar las etiquetas con el prefijo "s" tal como se muestra en el ejemplo siguiente.

```html
<s:form action="hello">
  <s:textfield name="name" label="Please enter your name" />
  <s:submit value="Say Hello" />
</s:form>
```